# laravel 5.2 where query builder with like doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I developed simple search .I want when enter a word in the search .searches in products table where title column contain this word. 
I write this code

```
$se=Request::get('search');
$result=Product::where('title','LIKE','%',$se,'%')->get();
```

what is the error in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$result=Product::where('title','LIKE','%',$se,'%')->get();
```

with

```
$result=Product::where('title','LIKE','%'.$se.'%')->get();
```

In the first one, you pass 5 different arguments to **where()** with third one **%** being the expression that needs to be matched. In the second one periods are used to prepend and append **%** to the string stored in **$se**.